# Python source code for issuing a new altcoin?

Tags: development, altcoin, python

I was wondering if anyone here know a python source code for making an altcoin? I found some tutorial on C++, but since I am not familiar with the language I cannot understand the code fully?
And if there are not any python code for that, what is the reason?

Comment: Why are you attempting to make an altcoin if you don't understand the code?

Comment: @MeshCollider Read my question again please. I do not understand the C++ code since I am not familiar with the language. There are several platforms out there that enable coin and token issuing without the need for programming. I am working on a scientific project for which I need to have full understanding of parameters involved and therefore looking a source code in python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TinyCoin](https://github.com/mit-dci/tinycoin), a small and easy to understand cryptocurrency written in Python. I'm still unsure exactly what you need because you con't create an altcoin from Bitcoin without knowing C++, Bitcoin is not written in python. But if you just need a python altcoin for learning purposes, this one should do the trick :)